# Learning Glade along with PyGTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

I've got my self sort of familiar with pygtk. I find it to be a lot of work to build GUI from code. So I turned to Glade. I'm trying to follow tutorials for Glade and PyGTK, and how they work together, however, I can't seems to find any tutorial for the GTKBuilder format.

I found a couple tutorials, like http://www.wmlug.org/pdf/Intro%20to%20PyGTK.pdf, http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6586?page=0,2
These helped me get into Glade, but I'm unsure how to proceed from there as libglade is deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

libglade has been replaced by GTK Builder which is basically a slight modification of libglade's API that's part of GTK+ proper.

Here are some links which should help you with that:

- [GTK+ and Glade3 GUI Programming Tutorial - Part 1](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html)
- [Libglade to GtkBuilder F.A.Q.](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-builder-libglade-faq.html)
- [learnpygtk.org - libglade vs gtkbuilder](http://www.learnpygtk.org/libglade-vs-gtkbuilder.html)
- [PyGTK Class Reference - gtk.Builder](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbuilder.html)
- [StackOverflow - What are the steps to convert from using libglade to GtkBuilder? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748872/what-are-the-steps-to-convert-from-using-libglade-to-gtkbuilder-python)